# Recursive function in C (Sequence)

Tags: c, function

I need to write a recursive function that recieve a number from the user and print a sequence from that number until `1` and then from `1` until the number.

> For example:
>   Number: 5
>   Output: 5 4 3 2 1 2 3 4 5

And I can't call the function twice.

Basically I just studied about recursive functions so I don't know too much about it.

I know about stoppage condition (of the `if`though not sure if this is the name).
So
`if(number == 1)` 
will get me just until `1`, and this isn't good enough.

Hope for clues and NOT for solution.

Comment: Did you try researching about this a bit before you post this question ? If yes, do post the code that you have so far .

Comment: Experiment with printing the value *twice*.

Comment: Clue: the function should look like `printSequence(current, max, direction)`

Comment: @xs0 that is 2 parameters too many - 1 would be enough

Comment: @ChrisTurner you're right.. in that case, the clue is: you can't apply tail-call optimization to the function

Comment: " And I can't call the function twice." -->  Hmmm I would think that `main()` calls the function `recurse()` once and then `recurse()` calls itself once.  That is 2 calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think of what you know and what you need.

1. You have an input number (e.g. 5)
2. That means you know how many times you'll need to print (5,4,3,2,1,2,3,4,5 - i.e. 5*2-1 = 9)
3. That means that by knowing how many times your function is called and by knowing the input, you can easily calculate the output.
4. So, calling a recursive function with an end condition (number of iterations) and an iterations counter could solve it.
5. A simpler solution (one parameter) would be this:

   - print input
   - call recursively with `input-1`
   - print input again
   - *This lets you print your current number in the start & end, and then go "inside" and print the next number (`number-1`) at the 2nd place (from start & end) and so on...*
   - **Note: You'll need to have a condition or this will never end. Think what your end condition should be...**

Comment: Care to comment on the DV?

Comment: Well, you gave me a new point of view, but then I dicided not to use a counter (5*2-1), since I could just print the numbers before & after the call.

Comment: Not my DV, but I think bullets 2-4 are not all that helpful.  There’s no need for counting.

Answer (score 3):

Recursive function algorithm:

Input: Number from which sequence is to be printed, say it `n` (assuming `n` is a positive number >=1).

1. Print the number `n`.
2. Check whether the number is equal to `1`. If it is then `return`, otherwise proceed to next step.
3. Call function recursively with argument `n-1`.
4. Print the number `n` after recursive call.

The `print` after recursive call will give you the sequence in reverse order while unwinding the stack.

Answer (score 1):

If `num` is the only parameter, use `num == 1` as the base case.

`Print num` before and after the recursive call. Recursive call uses the `num - 1`.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void count(unsigned int n)
{
    if (n)
    {
        printf("%u ", n);
        count(--n);
        if (n) printf("%u ", ++n);
    }
}

int main(void) 
{
    while ( 1 )
    {
        printf( "Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): " );

        unsigned int n;

        if ( scanf( "%u", &n ) != 1 || n == 0 ) break;

        putchar( '\n' );
        count( n );
        putchar( '\n' );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look like

```
Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 10

10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 
Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 5

5 4 3 2 1 2 3 4 5 
Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 0
```

Comment: With a little different condition you don't need the nested `if`. Or the prefix increment in the second `printf`.

Comment: OP specifically said he doesn't want a full solution.

Answer (score 0):

I feel kind of silly, previusly I did on my own recursive functions that printed from n to 1, or from 1 to n.. but now I truly knows what is the meaning of the order before & after the call.

```
void numToNum(int num) {
    if (num == 1) 
        printf("%d \n", num);
    else{
    printf("%d \n", num);
    numToNum(num - 1);
    printf("%d \n", num);
    }
}
```